# RMagick gem in Cloudfoundry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cloud-foundry

The rails 3.2 app needs RMagick gem.

From the support ticket, they say its in private PaaS.

But what for apps hosted on cloudfoundry.com itself, not in private PaaS?

Comment: RMagick requires an underlying image utility, ImageMagick. The Cloud Foundry engineering team is actively working to provide this utility to apps, so that libraries such as RMagick will work.

Comment: Well then have to wait or opt-in for heroku which already supports this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudFoundry.com recently added the ImageMagick binaries, which are necessary for libraries such as RMagick to work. The path is `/var/vcap/packages/imagemagick/bin/`. For example, to configure the paperclip gem add the following to `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/var/vcap/packages/imagemagick/bin/"
```

Comment: What would be the case if I am using CarrierWave instead of Paperclip?

Answer (score 1):

As Glenn has already said in his comment, RMagick has a dependency on the native library ImageMagick and the Cloud Foundry engineering team are currently working on integrating this in to the live environment.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say it's not supported on cloudfoundry.com: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/ruby-cf.html