# Is there a way to setup ImageMagick in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, rmagick, ibm-cloud

I've setup a Rails application (with the gem rmagick) on Bluemix and I need ImageMagick for the BlueImp image gallery to work.

Is this possible in one way or another?

Answer (score 0):

To use rmagic you have to install imagemagic in your server.

Check this link to install imagemagic:

> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-imagemagick/

Comment: Thanks but it was actually something like this that I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098643/rmagick-gem-in-cloudfoundry. Imagemagick Seems to already reside on BLuemix bu you need to refer to it in your environment file.